# Excel Data Import to DataTable with columns mapping?

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net, mapping

I am currently working on a data import application using vb.net and Sql Server,
I would like to import an excel whorksheet data to a data table, where the excel file is generated by another application,
so that columns names and orders are different than the datatable ones.
I am currently searching a method to map both source and destination columns in order to import data, after checking data in the excel file.

the data in the excel file could be in other format;
Example : For gender Data Column,

In SQL Server I used bit data type (if male=1 else 0)
But in Excel File it could be described a different format (Male, Female...)

Thanks in advance.

I succeeded to open and import the excel sheet and its columns, and I am seeking for a simplest way to map columns.